# Not geting response for 2015 H1B cap results

Tags: usa, h1-visa

I am living in US, My current status is F1 and I am working with CPT. My employer applied for H1B for me so that I can stay more than the limit of the CPT. I heard the lottery was done on April 28. But I didn't hear anything about my case. I don't know if I was selected or not. I called the lawyer filling my application and he said he got no response from uscis. My question is: Is there still a chance that I was selected and processing is taking some time? or Not getting any response means I am not selected.

Comment: same is my case. My lawyer says he has not received a notice till May 30. He has not received the refund package either. He thinks my case was not selected in the lottery. How can I get a confirmation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a chance. Premium processing entries are processed first and regular processing will follow slowly. Last year people were getting results as late as August and September.

You should however receive receipt notice fairly soon, if you haven't already. And by saying "you" I mean your employer and their lawyer, not you personally. They won't necessarily keep you posted about it unless you nag them.

Comment: I think the lawyer didn't receive a receipt. will he get a rejection notice if I wasn't selected in the lottery?

Comment: as far as i know he got no response till now? that means I am not selected or just means nothing?

Comment: means nothing. The lawyer will get a response.